# Handle useRef.current null in Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm facing an issue with a test that i need to do, it's the last test to get the 100% coverage.

I try several things but I didn't came out of it.

How can I set up a test to verify when a `useRef.current` is null?

This is my component:

```
const handleCopy = (): void => {
if (matrixTableRef.current === null) return

const clipboardItem = new ClipboardItem({
      'text/html': new Blob([matrixTableRef.current.outerHTML], {
type: 'text/html',
      }),
    })
navigator.clipboard.write([clipboardItem])

triggerCopyPopover()
}
```

This is the test I try to implement:

```
test('handleCopy does nothing when matrixTableRef.current is null', () => {

  // Render component with a mock ref
  const mockRef = { current: null };
  render(<Matrix matrixTableRef={mockRef} />);

  // Access the element that triggers handleCopy
  const copyButton = screen.getByTestId('copy-table');

  // Fire the event that triggers handleCopy
  fireEvent.click(copyButton);

  // Assert that navigator.clipboard.write was not called
  expect(navigator.clipboard.write).not.toHaveBeenCalled();


});
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to test the scenario where matrixTableRef.current is null in your React component, you can use jest.mock to mock the clipboard API and set up the test environment. Here's an example of how you can modify your test:

Assuming you are using Jest and testing-library/react:

// Import necessary modules

```
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import Matrix from './Matrix';

// Mock ClipboardItem and navigator.clipboard.write
jest.mock('clipboard-polyfill');

test('handleCopy does nothing when matrixTableRef.current is null', () => {
  // Render component with a mock ref
  const mockRef = { current: null };
  render(<Matrix matrixTableRef={mockRef} />);

  // Access the element that triggers handleCopy
  const copyButton = screen.getByTestId('copy-table');

  // Fire the event that triggers handleCopy
  fireEvent.click(copyButton);

  // Assert that navigator.clipboard.write was not called
  expect(navigator.clipboard.write).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

In this example the clipboard-polyfill library provides a mock implementation for the Clipboard API. Make sure to install this library (npm install clipboard-polyfill) if you haven't already.

This test assumes that your handleCopy function is directly calling navigator.clipboard.write within the component.

Comment: i got an error on the expect: 
`    Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

    Received has type:  function
    Received has value: [Function write]`

Comment: Try to mock the navigator.clipboard.write function using Jest. You can do this by creating a mock function and assigning it to navigator.clipboard.write. 

Here's how to do it:

`// Mock navigator.clipboard.write
navigator.clipboard.write = jest.fn();

test('handleCopy does nothing when matrixTableRef.current is null', () => {
  // Your test code here

  // Assert that navigator.clipboard.write was not called
  expect(navigator.clipboard.write).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});`

Comment: Alternatively, if you have already created a spy for navigator.clipboard.write using a library like jest-spy, make sure that the spy is correctly set up and used in the test.